# Change player in javascript game

Tags: javascript

Game: onClick startbutton > mathrandom for first player who starts the game.
4 Pictures: 2 of it > player1 and player2. another 2> Player turn.

need help:  on button click > next player turn

```
function game(){
    var PlayerTurn;
    PlayerTurn=parseInt(Math.random()*2);   
    if(PlayerTurn==0){PlayerTurn=1;window.document.player1.src="Cache/Player3.PNG";} 
    else{PlayerTurn=0;window.document.player2.src="Cache/Player4.PNG";} 
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function game(){
    var playerTurn;
    if (Math.random()>0.5){
        playerTurn=1;
       window.document.player1.src="Cache/Player3.PNG";
    } else {
        playerTurn=0;
        window.document.player2.src="Cache/Player4.PNG";
    }
}
```